# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in a spec

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I am working on Angular8 project using jest and jasmine as the testing configurations.

**.ts**

```
// all imports are done correctly

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xyz',
  templateUrl: './xyz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.scss']
})
export class XYZComponent implements OnInit {

  public info;
  public number;

  constructor(private InfoService: infoService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInfo();
  }

  public getInfo() {    
   this.info =  this.infoService.getData();   
   this.number = this.info.list[0].number;
  }

}
```

**.spec**

```
// all imports are done 

describe('XYZComponent', () => {
  let component: XYZComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<XYZComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ //imports done ],
      declarations: [ XYZComponent],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XYZComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.info = {
      'list':
      [
        {
       'fName':'Eddy',
       'lName':'He',
       'number: 123
     }
    ]
  }; 
   component.ngOnInIt(); 
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

When In the .spec files ngOnInit() is called it throws errors as follows :

● XYZComponent › should create

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

  43 |    this.info =  this.infoService.getData();
> 44 |    this.number = this.info.list[0].number;
     |                               ^
  46 |   }
```

Comment: Can you add the content of `this.infoService.getData()` please? I think the issue might be there.

Comment: yeas i can but where should I add in the .spec file can you guide me through?

Comment: Oh I means just the content of the method, as a separate code snippet. Wait nvm, I found the error, writing a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're doing:

```
component.info = {
  'list':
  [
    {
      'fName':'Eddy',
      'lName':'He',
      'number: 123
    }
  ]
};
```

Before calling `component.ngOnInit()`, it won't be enough, because in your `ngOnInit()` method, you're doing `this.info =  this.infoService.getData();`, overriding your `info` property.

And I believe that in this spec context, this method returns `undefined`.

A better way to do this would be to mock the service, prviding a fake `getData` method that returns the data you want the component to handle.

Or you can move `this.info =  this.infoService.getData()` to the constructor, as it doesn't depend on input data, and this will make your override work properly.

Comment: okay so I will try with the first approach to mock the service and provide it a fake call...  can you help me out with some examples on how to mock a service etc?

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-class-testing, search for "MockUserService".